# Javascript to view image in a new window from a thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, html

This code allows me to click on a thumbnail and see the original in a new window.
Clicking outside of the window does an autoclose.
So far so good.

However if the image is larger than the screen resolution I have to doubleclick on the Title Bar and then right click and "view image" to make it full screen. How can I change the code to prevent the image going off the screen?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

PositionX = 10;
PositionY = 10;
defaultWidth  = 600;
defaultHeight = 400;

var AutoClose = true;

function popImage(imageURL,imageTitle){
var imgWin = window.open('','_blank','scrollbars=no,resizable=1,width='+defaultWidth+',height='+defaultHeight+',left='+PositionX+',top='+PositionY);
if( !imgWin ) { return true; } //popup blockers should not cause errors
  imgWin.document.write('<html><head><title>'+imageTitle+'<\/title><script type="text\/javascript">\n'+
    'function resizeWinTo() {\n'+
    'if( !document.images.length ) { document.images[0] = document.layers[0].images[0]; }'+
    'var oH = document.images[0].height, oW = document.images[0].width;\n'+
    'if( !oH || window.doneAlready ) { return; }\n'+ //in case images are disabled
    'window.doneAlready = true;\n'+ //for Safari and Opera
    'var x = window; x.resizeTo( oW + 200, oH + 200 );\n'+
    'var myW = 0, myH = 0, d = x.document.documentElement, b = x.document.body;\n'+
    'if( x.innerWidth ) { myW = x.innerWidth; myH = x.innerHeight; }\n'+
    'else if( d && d.clientWidth ) { myW = d.clientWidth; myH = d.clientHeight; }\n'+
    'else if( b && b.clientWidth ) { myW = b.clientWidth; myH = b.clientHeight; }\n'+
    'if( window.opera && !document.childNodes ) { myW += 16; }\n'+
    'x.resizeTo( oW = oW + ( ( oW + 200 ) - myW ), oH = oH + ( (oH + 200 ) - myH ) );\n'+
    'var scW = screen.availWidth ? screen.availWidth : screen.width;\n'+
    'var scH = screen.availHeight ? screen.availHeight : screen.height;\n'+
    'if( !window.opera ) { x.moveTo(Math.round((scW-oW)/2),Math.round((scH-oH)/2)); }\n'+
    '}\n'+
    '<\/script>'+
    '<\/head><body onload="resizeWinTo();"'+(AutoClose?' onblur="self.close();"':'')+'>'+
    (document.layers?('<layer left="0" top="0">'):('<div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;display:table;">'))+
    '<img src='+imageURL+' alt="Loading image ..." title="" onload="resizeWinTo();">'+
    (document.layers?'<\/layer>':'<\/div>')+'<\/body><\/html>');
  imgWin.document.close();
  if( imgWin.focus ) { imgWin.focus(); }
  return false;
}
</script>

<a href="./mypic.jpg" onclick="return popImage(this.href,'Magnify');">
<img src="./mythumb.jpg" width="500" height="333" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Simple css : `max-width:100%`

Comment: @imvain2
It's part of a free code I copied years ago. I show photos when selecting them. I need to image to fill as much of the screen as possible. If the user clicks outside of the window they were left with the image windows still open so the auto close is a good thing. Some images need to fill the width and some the height depending on the orientation and size.

"modal" is completely new to me. I had a quick Google. That might do it. I will look into it. 

Can I create a full window maxed to the size of the screen with the image height or width maxed Any good source for syntax?